# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'parseUnits') - Hardhat js

Tags: javascript, solidity, chai, ethers.js, hardhat

When trying to use `ethers.utils.parseUnits("1", "ether")` in a test function an error is thrown `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'parseUnits')`.

```
const { deployments, ethers, getNamedAccounts } = require("hardhat")
const { assert, expect } = require("chai")
describe("FundMe", async function () {
    let fundMe
    let deployer
    const sendValue = ethers.utils.parseUnits("1", "ether")
})
```

I have tried using parseEther as well with the same result. In the [documentation specification for ethers.utils.parseUnits](https://docs.ethers.org/v5/api/utils/display-logic/#utils-parseUnits) it says to use just that. Is there another function that I am missing? Could my ethers config be incorrect?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As of [ethers version 6](https://docs.ethers.org/v6/api/utils/#parseUnits) `ethers.utils.parseUnit()` has been replaced by `ethers.parseUnit()`

Comment: The questioner is already stating he is trying to use ethers.utils.parseUnits. How does it answers the question? Can you elaborate please.?

Comment: ethers.utils.parseUnits does not exist in ethers 6. Using `ethers.parseUnits()` will yield the same result as using `ethers.utils.parseUnits()` in ethers 5 <=

Comment: https://docs.ethers.org/v5/api/utils/display-logic/#utils-parseUnits is also there in version 5.

Comment: `ethers.parseUnit()` is not available in ethers v5 as you have linked, only `ethers.utils.parseUnit()` is available in ethers v5. This was exactly the issue, I was trying to use `ethers.utils.parseUnit()` in ethers 6 which no longer exists.  Would it be more clear if I changed the answer to say `ethers.utils.parseUnit()` has been replaced by `ethers.parseUnit()`?

Comment: Oh, you are right. :)